# How can I put an element directly on the right of a centered element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have an element that looks just like this: [image: screenshot]

According to the designers plan, I need to put a little "?" just on right of the text (8.00$).
I use flexbox to center my elements. Basically, I nedd the ? to be directly on the right of the number. I don't want this element to push the number to the left. So, the 8 stays centered, the ? goes directly to the right without changing the position of the 8.

I did my own research and all the solutions given were using absolute positionning. I mean, it can work, but if I have bigger numbers, the ? will probably be over the text.

Do you have any suggestion?

Code, I don't know if it will work:

```css
/* weirdly, display:flex and width:100% have a stroke over them in the console */

.compare-row-small-box {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.compare-row-box-title {
  --text-opacity: 1;
  color: #4a5568;
  color: rgba(74, 85, 104, var(--text-opacity));
  font-size: 12px;
}

.compare-row-box-content {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="space-y-1 compare-row-small-box">
  <p class="compare-row-box-title">Frais mensuels estimés</p>
  <div class="compare-row-box-content"><span>8.00 $</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Need it beside the number? You need it between the 0 and $ or after the $?

Comment: @epascarello after the $, I should have specified this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS after with content you can add the ? after the $

```css
.compare-row-small-box {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.compare-row-box-title {
  --text-opacity: 1;
  color: #4a5568;
  color: rgba(74, 85, 104, var(--text-opacity));
  font-size: 12px;
}

.compare-row-box-content {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.compare-row-box-content span {
  position: relative; 
}
.compare-row-box-content span::after{
  content: '?';
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="space-y-1 compare-row-small-box">
  <p class="compare-row-box-title">Frais mensuels estimés</p>
  <div class="compare-row-box-content"><span>8.00 $</span></div>
</div>


<div class="space-y-1 compare-row-small-box">
  <p class="compare-row-box-title">Frais mensuels estimés</p>
  <div class="compare-row-box-content x"><span>1238.00 $</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the '?' in an :after pseudo-element like this.

```css
/* weirdly, display:flex and width:100% have a stroke over them in the console */

.compare-row-small-box {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.compare-row-box-title {
  --text-opacity: 1;
  color: #4a5568;
  color: rgba(74, 85, 104, var(--text-opacity));
  font-size: 12px;
}

.compare-row-box-content {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.compare-row-box-content span::after {
  content: '?';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="space-y-1 compare-row-small-box">
  <p class="compare-row-box-title">Frais mensuels estimés</p>
  <div class="compare-row-box-content"><span>8.00 $</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to add your character and use relative positioning to give it some space.

```css
/* weirdly, display:flex and width:100% have a stroke over them in the console */

.compare-row-small-box {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.compare-row-box-title {
  --text-opacity: 1;
  color: #4a5568;
  color: rgba(74, 85, 104, var(--text-opacity));
  font-size: 12px;
}

.compare-row-box-content {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.compare-row-box-content span::after {
  content: "?"; 
  color: darkorange;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  left: 0.5em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 300ms linear;
}

.compare-row-box-content:hover span::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="space-y-1 compare-row-small-box">
  <p class="compare-row-box-title">Frais mensuels estimés</p>
  <div class="compare-row-box-content"><span>8.00 $</span></div>
</div>

<div class="space-y-1 compare-row-small-box">
  <p class="compare-row-box-title">Frais mensuels estimés</p>
  <div class="compare-row-box-content"><span>800000.00 $</span></div>
</div>
```